# Dual boot on Lenovo with Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, lenovo

I am a relatively new Ubuntu user having been using 16.04 on an ancient HP laptop.  I have now been bought a new Lenovo "Idea Centre" by my wife but would like to at least have Ubuntu installed as dual boot (initall) however I hae read some horror stories about issues with 17.10 and Lenovo pc's being irredeemably screwed up when Ubuntu is installed as a dual boot.

Has this issue been fixed ?  Am I safe to install 18.?? on my new Lenovo ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is safe, Lenovo and Dell have better support for Ubuntu and other linux distros. If you are a new user ubuntu installer gives and option of "erase disk and install ubuntu", "Install it alongside windows", "manual partitioning". I would recomend you use the "Install Ubuntu alongside windows" option, as you are new and can't do manual partitioning. Ubuntu will automaticaly give you dual boot space, boot and all partition setup. It wont disturb any of your windows don't worry. You will have 2 options when you boot windows or ubuntu. Have Fun !